# ARCH effect in GARCH model

Tags: statistics, time-series, finance

After fitting GARCH model in R and obtain the output, how do I know whether there is any evidence of ARCH effect?

I am not toosure whether I have to check in optimal parameters, Information criteria, Q-statistics on standardized residuals, ARCM LM Tests, Nyblom stability test, Sign Bias Test or Adjusted Pearson Goodness-of-fit test?

I assume I have to check under ARCH LM Tests, and if the p-value is rather high, there is an ARCH effect, am I right?

Thank you

Comment: You mean Arch in the original series or in the garch residuals? For the first you could try Arch LM until you past the test

Answer (score 0):

You need to start by looking for second order persistence in the return series itself before going on to fit a GARCH model. Lets work through a quick example of how this will work

Start by getting the return series. Here I will use the `quantmod` library to load in the data for *SPDR S&P 500 ETF* or *SPY*

```
library(quantmod)
library(PerformanceAnalytics) 

rtn<-getSymbols(c('SPY'),return.class='ts')
```

Next, calculate the return series either yourself or using the `Return.calculate` function as provided by the `PerformanceAnalytics` library

```
Rtn <- diff(log(SPY[,"SPY.Close"])) * 100

#OR

Rtn <- Return.calculate(SPY[,"SPY.Close"], method = c("compound","simple")[2]) * 100
```

Now, lets have a look at the persistence of the first and second order moments of the series. For second order moments, lets use the squared return series as a proxy.

```
Plotdata<-cbind(Rtn, Rtn^2)
plot.zoo(Plotdata)
```

[image: ACF_plots]

There remains strong first persistence in returns and there is clearly periods of strong second order persistence as seen in the squared returns.

We can now formally start testing for ARCH-effects. A formal test for ARCH effects is LBQ stats on squared returns:

```
Box.test(coredata(Rtn^2), type = "Ljung-Box", lag = 12)

    Box-Ljung test

data:  coredata(Rtn^2)
X-squared = 2001.2, df = 12, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

We can clearly reject the null hypothesis of independence in a given time series. (ARCH-effects)

Fin.Ts also provides the ARCH-LM test for conditional heteroskedasticity in the returns:

```
library(FinTS)
ArchTest(Rtn)
    ARCH LM-test; Null hypothesis: no ARCH effects

data:  Rtn
Chi-squared = 722.19, df = 12, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

This supports the conclusion of the LBQ test that *ARCH-effects* are present.